# Why are landscape pages causing issues with page numbers/section headers/footers in officeverse?

Tags: r, r-markdown, officer, officedown

When knitting the below `Rmd` **with a landscape page** and viewing the word output produced by it, it becomes apparent that **page two seems to be missing**. Also, page numbering in the footer of the page only starts after the landscape page has been included.

Conversely, when knitting the below `Rmd` **without a landscape page** there are **no such issues**.

Why is that and how can I make the document with landscape pages behave like the one without?

***With landscape page:***

````yaml
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
```

<!---BLOCK_TOC--->

# Chapter 1
# Chapter 2
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->
# Chapter 3
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->
# Chapter 4
\newpage
# Chapter 5
\newpage
# Chapter 6
````

***Without landscape page:***

````yaml
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
```

<!---BLOCK_TOC--->

# Chapter 1
# Chapter 2
# Chapter 3
# Chapter 4
\newpage
# Chapter 5
\newpage
# Chapter 6
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page 2:**
Using `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP{break_page: "nextPage"}--->` instead of `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->` fixes this.

**Page numbers in footer starting on page 1:**
Add the below chunk right after `<!---BLOCK_TOC--->`. The functions in this chunk are implemented in the `officer` package.

````
```{r}
footer_default <- block_list(fpar(run_word_field(field = "PAGE"),
                                  fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center") ))

block_section(prop_section(footer_default = footer_default))
```
````

**All together:**

````yaml
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
library(officer) # 0.6.2
```

<!---BLOCK_TOC--->

```{r}
footer_default <- block_list(fpar(run_word_field(field = "PAGE"),
                                  fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center") ))

block_section(prop_section(footer_default = footer_default))
```

# Chapter 1
# Chapter 2
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->
# Chapter 3
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP{break_page: "nextPage"}--->
# Chapter 4
\newpage
# Chapter 5
\newpage
# Chapter 6
````

Relevant references:
https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/discussions/103
https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/discussions/138